# Generate rebel.xml in the root of jar module with jrebel-maven-plugin

Tags: java, xml, maven, maven-plugin, jrebel

I have a maven multi-module project and I want to use jrebel, this is part of my pom.xml

```
<build>
...
  <plugins>
  ...
    <plugin>
    <groupId>org.zeroturnaround</groupId>
    <artifactId>jrebel-maven-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>1.1.5</version>
    <configuration>
      <relativePath>../../</relativePath>
      <rootPath>/Path/to/my/clear/case/view</rootPath>
      <addResourcesDirToRebelXml>true</addResourcesDirToRebelXml>
      <alwaysGenerate>true</alwaysGenerate>
    </configuration>
    <executions>
      <execution>
        <id>generate-rebel-xml</id>
        <phase>process-resources</phase>
        <goals>
          <goal>generate</goal>
        </goals>
      </execution>
    </executions>
  </plugin>
```

With this, if I type `mvn jrebel:generate`, the plugin creates all the rebel.xml files in `../target/classes/`, but I need, as it is explained in the page of Jrebel, for my `jar modules` to have the rebel.xml in the root, not in `../target/classes/`.

Is there any way using jrebel-maven-plugin to auto-generate the rebel.xml files of jar modules in the root?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: If the _rebel.xml_ file is in _target/classes_ in your *module*, then it will end up in the root of the corresponding *JAR*.

Comment: Yeah, you're right @Tome. My bad, I've tried so many things that I was confused. This works fine. Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

rebel.xml will be copied from target/classes to .jar file root while building it.